# array.reduce( ) using index on multiple arguments

Tags: javascript

- I have a SQL with 4 columns: salesman_name | sales | goal | month
- The goal column has an unique value for each month and the sales column is the sum of the sales in that month.
- With jQuery I put these values into 3 different arrays:

```
$(resultset).each(function (i, el) {
        arraySalesman.push(el.salesman_name);
        arraySales.push(el.sales);
        arrayGoal.push(el.goal);
});
```

- When I filter my dataset for x months, i have x values for sales and x values for goals for each salesman. I need to reduce those values to an unique sales and an unique goal value for each salesman (accumulated value).
- I've tried something like that on JavaScript:

```
var dataObjSales = arraySalesman.reduce((t, c, i) => (t[c] = (t[c] || 0) + arraySales[i], t), {});
var dataObjGoal = arraySalesman.reduce((t, c, i) => (t[c] = (t[c] || 0) + arrayGoal[i], t), {});
```

- It returns to me something like that:

```
console.log("dataObjSales", dataObjSales);

dataObjSales
{…}
​
"Salesman1": 1650574.98
​
"Salesman2": 829888.27
​
"Salesman3": 1186831.46
​
"Salesman3": 1342287.91
​
"Salesman4": 3185057.64
​
"Salesman5": 387644.28
​
"Salesman6": 2262157.5
​
<prototype>: Object { … }
```

- I need to transform this into an object with 3 properties: Obj.salesman, Obj.sales and Obj.goals. Can I do it into the first reduce? Or can I transform these 2 reduces and the salesman_name array into an object with 3 properties?

Comment: Can you sketch out how the result is supposed to look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can make good use of a `Map`:

```js
const arraySalesperson = ["John", "Alice", "Bob", "John", "John", "Alice"];
const arraySales = [100, 420, 138, 89, 74, 86];
const arrayGoals = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

// create a map
const resultsBySalesperson = new Map();

// traverse the list of salespersons
for (let i = 0; i < arraySalesperson.length; i++) {
  const name = arraySalesperson[i];
  
  // see if it already exists in the map
  let salesperson = resultsBySalesperson.get(name);

  if (!salesperson) {
    // if not, let's create an object now
    salesperson = {
      name: name,
      sales: 0,
      goals: 0
    };
    // store it in the map
    resultsBySalesperson.set(name, salesperson);
  }

  // update the object
  salesperson.sales += arraySales[i];
  salesperson.goals += arrayGoals[i];
}

// here you have the map ready with both sales and goal properly accumulated
console.info([...resultsBySalesperson.entries()]);
```